# How can I set this div's to display inline?

Tags: css, drupal-8, display

I can't figure out how to target these div's. They're auto created by Drupal so I can't change any of the html. I'm just trying to use css to set `display: inline-block;` but I've got no idea how to target the div's.

I tried using a ridiculous selector with about ten classes all in a row. Obviously that didn't work but I can't pick anything that I could use.

If you really want to see what I tried, it's this

`.js-view-dom-id-2440d996405b92b9e79e4f45b4592d697bcee994b7823526688871e9cae9b36e .item-list ul li .node .node__content .inline .quickedit-field div{display: inline-block;}`

I figure it's probably just easiest to give you the url to the actual site so you can see what i mean in dev tools. Go to `naclc.info/jobs` I'm trying to make the closing date display on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS flex property instead of using `display: inline`.

Assuming Ul is not coming dynamically. You can target DIVs like:

```
ul.links + div { display: flex; }
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to be working for now but I'm a bit concerned that it might break something else on the site. I'll keep a close eye out though. Thanks.